# What is the correct format to upgrade pip3 when the default pip is pip2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cygwin, pip, python-3.4

I develop for both `Python 2` and `3.`
Thus, I have to use both `pip2` and `pip3.`

When using `pip3 -` I receive this upgrade request (last two lines):

```
$ pip3 install arrow
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): arrow in c:\program files (x86)\python3.5.1\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-dateutil in c:\program files (x86)\python3.5.1\lib\site-packages (from arrow)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.5 in c:\program files (x86)\python3.5.1\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil->arrow)
You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 8.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

My default `pip` is for `Python 2,` namely:

```
$  python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

However, none of the following *explicit* commands succeed in upgrading the `Python 3 pip:`

```
$  python -m pip3 install --upgrade pip3
/bin/python: No module named pip3

$  python -m pip install --upgrade pip3
Collecting pip3
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip3 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pip3

$  python -m pip install --upgrade pip3.4
Collecting pip3.4
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip3.4 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pip3.4
```

### What is the correct command to upgrade pip3 when it is not the default pip?

Environment:

```
$ python3 -V
Python 3.4.3
$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW 2.5.2(0.297/5/3) 2016-06-23 14:27 i686 Cygwin
```

Comment: I usually use `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Just use the `pip3` command you already have:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

The installed *project* is called `pip`, always. The `pip3` command is tied to your Python 3 installation and is an alias for `pip`, but the latter is shadowed by the `pip` command in your Python 2 setup.

You can do it with the associated Python binary too; if it executable as `python3`, then use that:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Again, the project is called `pip`, and so is the module that is installed into your `site-packages` directory, so stick to that name for the `-m` command-line option and for the `install` command.

Comment: 'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: @DJHowarth: *if it executable as python3*

Comment: How do I install tensorflow if pip3 isnt recogized?
 C:\Python36\Scripts>python -m pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
C:\Python36\python.exe: No module named pip3

Comment: @DJHowarth: The module is called `pip`, not `pip3`. The *command* might be called `pip3`, but `-m` only loads modules.

Comment: @DJHowarth: use `python -m pip install`; your `python.exe` is already the correct Python version.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me as you can see in the error message I stored [on onlinegdb](https://onlinegdb.com/SJtvStNRz)

Comment: @Marine1: When you ran with `sudo`, your download timed out. Why didn't you try to download again?

Comment: @Marine1: You could also manually download `https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/74/ecd13431bcc456ed390b44c8a6e917c1820365cbebcb6a8974d1cd045ab4/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl` first, then use `sudo pip3 install --upgrade <download/location/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl>`.

Answer (score 4):

When I searched for "how to update pip3" this came up. I had the problem described [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/25752) in mind:

### The Problem

Upgrading with pip3 might make point `pip` to the Python 3 version.

It seems as if this is not the case (any more).

### The solution

Update the one you want to keep after the one you want to upgrade. Hence

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
pip2 install --upgrade pip --force-reinstall
```

will make sure that `pip` points to `pip2`.