# upgrade pip 18 display failure in terminal but successful in pycharm

Tags: python, pip, upgrade

On Windows 10, in Powershell (administration) and Python version 3.7

Upgrade pip via the `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` in terminal.

But `pip -V` gives me the pip version still 10.01?

[in the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qm3ON.png)
In the pycharm(2018.2 on the same computer, pip module is v18!

How could get upgrade "pip" properly?

Comment: try  `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` for python3

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39129450/what-is-the-correct-format-to-upgrade-pip3-when-the-default-pip-is-pip2/39129467